# Python *.count is returning a letter instead of a number

Tags: python, string, count, int

I am attempting to count the number of times the letter C appears in a list. When I use:

```
count = data[data.count('C')]
print ("There are", count, "molecules in the file")
```

when the code is run, it returns `There are . molecules in the file`
If I type data.count('C') after the program has run, it returns the correct value (43). I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: You are using `data` twice .... `count = data[data.count('C')]` should be `count =data.count('C')`

Comment: That good guy who has upvoted all the answers!!! ... :)

Comment: @BhargavRao  You need 'em every once in a while... to counter that bad guy who downvotes all the answers.

Comment: Thank you all very much for your help. It works like it should now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could this line have something to do with it, maybe? ;)

```
count = data[data.count('C')] # This gives you the value at index data.count('C') of data
```

The actual count, as you later put it, is:

```
count = data.count('C')
```

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing the 1st line with:

`count = data.count('C')`

Answer (score 1):

Modify the first line:

```
count = data.count('C')
```

The problem is that you were printing the n'th element of the list data (where n=count) instead of the count itself.

As a side note, this is a better way to print your result:

```
print "There are {0} molecules in the file".format(count)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `data` twice ....

```
count = data[data.count('C')]
```

should be

```
count =data.count('C')
```

This would print

```
There are 43 molecules in the file
```

Answer (score 1):

The good news is that you're getting the correct value from the method.

The bad news is that you're using it incorrectly.

You're using the result as an index into the string, which then results in a character from the string. Stop doing that.